# Identifying Clusters After Analysis

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, data-analysis

I have a dataset which consists of metrics of web traffic from multiple different brands. My goal is to see if there are any relationships between brands based on the metrics.

My question is once I completed the clustering analysis (Kmeans and PCA) process and how do I know which brands are in which cluster?

I was thinking about creating another feature that lists each of the brands. I would recoding each brand with a numeric value based on the volume of the web traffic.

Comment: The key should tell you. Perhaps you could supply your code?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you have some unique object identifier.

For example, the row number.

Comment: Thank you for your help I appreciate your answer!